# Trie ending at current node or node after

Tags: c++, data-structures

Given that a trie has nodes as such:

```
struct TrieNode {
    map<char, TrieNode> children; 
    bool endOfWord = false;

    TrieNode() {}
};
```

Would it be better for the endOfWord bool to be true at the end of the word (case 1)

`c-a-[t] <--- endOfWord = true;`

or to create an empty char Node and have the endOfWord there (case 2)

`c-a-t-[ ] <--- endOfWord = true;`

From all the tutorials I saw, they recommend the latter choice but wouldn't that make matters more confusing? For a trie that contains beckoned and beckon, case 1 would look like

`b-e-c-k-o-[n]-e-[d]`

but case 2 would have

`b-e-c-k-o-n-[e]-d-[ ]`

Or is this simply a matter of how my trie is implemented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go with the first - end-of-word marked on the letter rather than the successor.

Primary reason: when searching, one doesn't need to look for an empty EoW successor - save CPU time (especially if the empty nodes needs loading in the CPU cache, but this can be alleviated by using a single terminator node. That is, unless one needs to backref the parent from the children - beat me if I can imagine why would someone need it).

Answer (score 0):

What's the point in creating additional objects to represent grapf leafs? In any algorithm implementation you'll have to check if `endOfWord` is set to `true` or `false`. Introducting additional layer of objects won't make implementation easier, it'll result in memory waste.

Answer (score 0):

One reason could be that if you use a special character (e.g. code point 0), you wouldn't need the end-of-word flag at all.

Comment: Like if the children map contains a certain character, it would denote the end of word?

Comment: Yes. Code point zero might be a good choice, as it's typically used as a string terminator in C